# To optimize four parameters in Python Scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b, with an error

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am coding an algorithm for active learning, using L-BFGS algorithm from scipy.optimize. I need to optimize four parameters: `alpha`,`beta`,`W` and `gamma`.

However, it does not work, with the error of

```
optimLogitLBFGS = sp.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b(func, x0=np.array(alpha,beta,W,gamma), fprime=func_grad)
ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted
```

Note that, in last sentence of the code, `x0` is the initial guess of the four paramters. If I change to `x0=np.array((alpha,beta,W,gamma),dtype=float)`, I got an error of

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I am not sure why the error happens.

```
from sys import argv
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as sps

num_labeler = 3
num_instance = 5

X = np.array([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4],[5,5,5,5]])
Z = np.array([1,0,1,0,1])
Y = np.array([[1,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[1,0,0]])

W = np.array([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]])
gamma = np.ones(5)
alpha = np.ones(4)
beta = 1


def log_p_y_xz(yit,zi,sigmati): #log P(y_it|x_i,z_i)
    return np.log(sps.norm(zi,sigmati).pdf(yit))#tested

def log_p_z_x(alpha,beta,xi): #log P(z_i=1|x_i)
    return -np.log(1+np.exp(-np.dot(alpha,xi)-beta))#tested

def sigma_eta_ti(xi, w_t, gamma_t): # 1+exp(-w_t x_i -gamma_t)^-1
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(xi,w_t)-gamma_t)) #tested

def df_alpha(X,Y,Z,W,alpha,beta,gamma):#df/dalpha
    return np.sum((2/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(alpha,X[i])-beta))-1)*np.exp(-np.dot(alpha,X[i])-beta)*X[i]/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(alpha,X[i])-beta))**2 for i in range (num_instance))

def df_beta(X,Y,Z,W,alpha,beta,gamma):#df/dbelta
    return np.sum((2/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(alpha,X[i])-beta))-1)*np.exp(-np.dot(alpha,X[i])-beta)/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(alpha,X[i])-beta))**2 for i in range (num_instance))

def df_w(X,Y,Z,W,alpha,beta,gamma):#df/sigma * sigma/dw
    return np.sum(np.sum((-3)*(Y[i][t]**2-(-np.log(1+np.exp(-np.dot(alpha,X[i])-beta)))*(2*Y[i][t]-1))*(1/(1/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(X[i],W[t])-gamma[t])))**4)*(1/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(X[i],W[t])-gamma[t])))*(1-(1/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(X[i],W[t])-gamma[t]))))*X[i]+(1/(1/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(X[i],W[t])-gamma[t])))**2)*(1/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(X[i],W[t])-gamma[t])))*(1-(1/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(X[i],W[t])-gamma[t]))))*X[i]for t in range(num_labeler)) for i in range (num_instance))

def df_gamma(X,Y,Z,W,alpha,beta,gamma):#df/sigma * sigma/dgamma
    return np.sum(np.sum((-3)*(Y[i][t]**2-(-np.log(1+np.exp(-np.dot(alpha,X[i])-beta)))*(2*Y[i][t]-1))*(1/(1/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(X[i],W[t])-gamma[t])))**4)*(1/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(X[i],W[t])-gamma[t])))*(1-(1/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(X[i],W[t])-gamma[t]))))+(1/(1/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(X[i],W[t])-gamma[t])))**2)*(1/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(X[i],W[t])-gamma[t])))*(1-(1/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(X[i],W[t])-gamma[t]))))for t in range(num_labeler)) for i in range (num_instance))

def func(para, *args):
    #the function to minimize
    #parameters
    alpha = para[0]#alpha should be an array
    beta = para[1]
    W = para[2]
    gamma = para[3]
    #args
    X = args [0]
    Y = args[1]
    Z = args[2]        
    return  np.sum(np.sum(log_p_y_xz(Y[i][t], Z[i], sigma_eta_ti(X[i],W[t],gamma[t]))+log_p_z_x(alpha, beta, X[i]) for t in range(num_labeler)) for i in range (num_instance))


def func_grad(para, *args):
    #para have 4 values
    alpha = para[0]#alpha should be an array
    beta = para[1]
    W = para[2]
    gamma = para[3]
    #args
    X = args [0]
    Y = args[1]
    Z = args[2]
    #gradiants
    d_f_a = df_alpha(X,Y,Z,W,alpha,beta,gamma)
    d_f_b = df_beta(X,Y,Z,W,alpha,beta,gamma)
    d_f_w = df_w(X,Y,Z,W,alpha,beta,gamma)
    d_f_g = df_gamma(X,Y,Z,W,alpha,beta,gamma)
    return np.array([d_f_a, d_f_b,d_f_w,d_f_g])


optimLogitLBFGS = sp.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b(func, x0 =np.array(alpha,beta,W,gamma), fprime = func_grad)
```

Comment: ``np.array(alpha,beta,W,gamma)`` in the last line is not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scipy optimization routines can only optimize a **one-dimensional vector** of parameters. It looks like you're trying to optimize a tuple of values which contain a mix of scalars, vectors, and matrices.

What you'll want to do is flatten all the relevant parameter values into a one-dimensional array, and have your `func` unwrap and set these appropriately.

---

Edit: I'd proceed by creating a convenience function which extracts your parameters; for example:

```
def get_params(para):
    # extract parameters from 1D parameter vector
    assert len(para) == 22
    alpha = para[0:4]
    beta = para[4]
    W = para[5:17].reshape(3, 4)
    gamma = para[17:]
    return alpha, beta, gamma, W

def func(para, *args):
    #the function to minimize
    #parameters
    alpha, beta, gamma, W = get_params(para)

    #args
    X = args [0]
    Y = args[1]
    Z = args[2]        
    return  np.sum(np.sum(log_p_y_xz(Y[i][t], Z[i], sigma_eta_ti(X[i],W[t],gamma[t]))+log_p_z_x(alpha, beta, X[i]) for t in range(num_labeler)) for i in range (num_instance))


def func_grad(para, *args):
    #para have 4 values
    alpha, beta, gamma, W = get_params(para)

    #args
    X = args [0]
    Y = args[1]
    Z = args[2]
    #gradiants
    d_f_a = df_alpha(X,Y,Z,W,alpha,beta,gamma)
    d_f_b = df_beta(X,Y,Z,W,alpha,beta,gamma)
    d_f_w = df_w(X,Y,Z,W,alpha,beta,gamma)
    d_f_g = df_gamma(X,Y,Z,W,alpha,beta,gamma)
    return np.array([d_f_a, d_f_b,d_f_w,d_f_g])


x0 = np.concatenate([np.ravel(alpha), np.ravel(beta), np.ravel(W), np.ravel(gamma)])
optimLogitLBFGS = sp.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b(func, x0=x0, fprime=func_grad)
```

It doesn't run because your `func()` and `func_grad()` require additional arguments which are not specified in your code snippet, but this change solves the specific problem you were asking about.

Comment: Your comment is right... But I don't know how to flatten all the parameters to 1-dim array...

Comment: So could you please provide me some hints? thanks a lot~

Comment: Thank you so much for your code. It is very helpful. The last line of the code should be :  `optimLogitLBFGS = sp.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b(func, x0 = x0, args = (X,Y,Z), fprime = func_grad)`.  Still I can not run my program with the error `_lbfgsb.error: failed in converting 7th argument `g' of _lbfgsb.setulb to C/Fortran array    0-th dimension must be fixed to 22 but got 4`. I do not know why

Comment: I will accept your answer, although I can not run my program:) Your code is  indeed very helpful.

Comment: ``func_grad`` needs to return a vector the same length as ``x0``, which means the output of your ``df`` functions must be the same size as the input. This is not the case: I'd focus your effort on making sure the ``df`` functions are defined correctly.

Comment: Oh, I see you asked your question again and got a [similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33386294/python-scipy-optimize-fmin-l-bfgs-b-error-occurs). Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. I know what is the problem. However, when I use 'optimBFGS = sp.optimize.minimize(func,x0 = x0,args = (X,Y,Z))', I can get a result. It is strange to me, though.~