# How can I get the arrays of the results from the Scipy Optimize function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am now using `scipy.optimize.minimize` function for my algorithm. The code is something like:

```
optim = scipy.optimize.minimize(blablabla)
print optim
```

Then I got the results printed in the console.

```
status: 0
  success: True
     nfev: 42
 hess_inv: <20x20 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
      fun: 97330.117758336462
        x: array([ 0.34842437,  0.31432181,  0.3231227 ,  0.82165996,  0.01639795,
    ])
  message: 'CONVERGENCE: NORM_OF_PROJECTED_GRADIENT_<=_PGTOL'
```

However, I need to use the results again in the code, and I wish to get the array of `x` and the value of `fun`. How to obtain them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access them with `optim.x` and `optim.fun`.

Comment: It does not work. I got `print optim.x                                  
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'x'`

Comment: are you sure you are not doing something else wrong? it should return a OptimizeResult, not a tuple... can you show your exact code?

Comment: Thank you. My code is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33386294/python-scipy-optimize-fmin-l-bfgs-b-error-occurs, and the last line of the code is modified to `optimBFGS = sp.optimize.minimize(func,x0 = x0,args = (X,Y,Z))`

Comment: and then you just have  `print optimBFGS.x` and it throws?

Comment: Yes. `print optimBFGS.x`

Comment: Well, your code works for me (using spyder and interactive console) so the problem should be in your interface I suppose... or maybe your packages or not up to date?

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem. I use scipy-0.16.1-win32-superpack-python2.7, and Eclipse(LUNA) with PyDev.

Comment: Actually, I got a warning underlying `optimize` in the code `optimBFGS = sp.optimize.minimize(func,x0 = x0,args = (X,Y,Z))`. The warning gives: `Undefined variable from import: optimize`. If I add `from scipy import optimize`, the warning still exists.

Comment: you should use `import scipy.optimise`

Comment: with `import scipy.optimize` and `optimBFGS = scipy.optimize.minimize(func,x0 = x0,method = 'L-BFGS-B',args = (X,Y,Z))`, I got the result. Thank you so much. But I still do not know why it can be resolved like this. I do not have auto compeletion when I type `print optimBFGS.` for `x`.  Why `sp.optimize.minimize` does not work-_-bbb